# AES encryption / Decryption scala

Tags: scala, aes

I am new to scala. I'm using spray to create Rest API. I want to consume a response from some other application(i.e. python application). For that, I required some sort of encryption between them. I'm searching for the AES library in scala, but haven't found one. Is there any library for AES encryption in scala which I can use?

Answer (score 2):

A lot of libraries stay on Java because most JVM languages like Scala have good interop with java so just use it. Check this [Java 256-bit AES Password-Based Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption).